# Cómo puedo hacer una consulta SELECT a dos tablas diferentes en MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

En mi base de datos necesito hacer una consulta a dos tablas: `product` y `price_product`

Estas son los campos de ambas tablas:

[image: las dos tablas]

La consulta que hago es la siguiente:

```
SELECT productCode,description,price 
FROM product, price_product 
WHERE price_product.flagErased = 0 AND
product.flagErased = 0 AND
product.idProduct=price_product.idProduct 
GROUP BY description 
ORDER BY description ASC 
LIMIT 1000
```

El problema es que esa consulta me muestra el primer precio que se le asigna en la tabla `product_price` y yo quisiera que me mostrara el ultimo precio, asignado en la tabla `price_product`.

Alguna sugerencia o modificación?

Cómo debo realizar la consutla para que me muestre el ultimo precio insertado en la tabla `price_product`?

No se si esa consulta debe ser realizada teniendo en cuenta la última fecha que se le agregó, o simplemente pidiendo el último que se agregó del producto (pienso que la segunda tiene que procesar menos, ya que no debe comparar fechas, solo debe buscar el ulitmo insertado, pero ni idea de como acomodarlo).

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda que puedan ofrecerme.

Comment: Las bases de datos no conocen el concepto de ultimo insertado (si esta en los logs, pero no queda, por lo general, registros en las tablas, salvo que se active algun tipo de auditoria).

Answer (score 0):

Aprovechando que el `Id` es `int` y es incremental puedes buscar el último agrupado por código del producto, así reduces el universo de posibilidades. Este es un ejemplo en SQL, es muy similar a MySQL, espero que esto te ayude:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Producto(
    ProductoId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Fecha datetime NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE Producto_Precio(
    ProductoPrecioId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductoId INT REFERENCE Producto (ProductoId),
    Precio DECIMAL(12,2),
    FechaCreacion DATETIME
)

 INSERT INTO Producto VALUES('iphone', GETDATE())
 INSERT INTO Producto VALUES('xiaomi', GETDATE())

 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (1,'1300',GETDATE())
 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (1,'900',GETDATE())
 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (1,'800',GETDATE())
 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (1,'700',GETDATE())

 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (2,'700',GETDATE())
 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (2,'800',GETDATE())
 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (2,'900',GETDATE())
 INSERT INTO Producto_Precio values (2,'1300',GETDATE())

 SELECT 
    p.ProductoId,
    p.Descripcion,
    p.Fecha,
    pp.Precio,
    pp.ProductoPrecioId
 From Producto AS p
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ProductoPrecioId) AS ProductoPrecioId, ProductoId FROM Producto_Precio GROUP BY  ProductoId) AS i ON p.ProductoId = i.ProductoId
    INNER JOIN Producto_Precio  AS pp ON i.ProductoPrecioId = pp.ProductoPrecioId
```